# jQuery AJAX sequential calls with MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I've got an odd setup in an MVC project, where I have an `@Ajax.BeginForm()` with the following fields:-

- Address Line 1
- Address Line 2
- Town
- County
- PostCode

We require to go to Google Geocode with this address, and get the latitude and longitude on click of the submit button on the Ajax form. So:-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditLocation", "Location", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "new-locations", OnBegin = "return OnBegin()", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess()", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore }, new { @id = "EditLocationForm" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <!-- Standard Text Fields -->
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Latitude)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Longitude)
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn--gradient btn--right" id="EditLocationSubmit" />  
}

function OnBegin() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Location/CheckAddress/',
        datatype: "json",
        async: false,
        data: { addressLine1: $("#BrandLocationAddress_AddressLine1").val(), addressLine2: $("#BrandLocationAddress_AddressLine2").val(), town: $("#BrandLocationAddress_Town").val(), county: $("#BrandLocationAddress_County").val(), postcode: $("#BrandLocationAddress_Postcode").val(), },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data !== "NORESULTS") {
                $("#Latitude").val(data.Latitude);
                $("#Longitude").val(data.Longitude);
                return true;
            }
            else {

            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

The results of the /Location/CheckAddress/ bring back a latitude and longitude as expected, but the `Ajax.BeginForm()` goes into the form submission before the two #Latitude and #Longitude fields are populated. When I look in the `[HttpPost]` of the model, latitude and longitude are 0.

When I post a second time, the fields are the correct latitude and longitude values. I think this might be because `OnBegin()` is allowing the `Ajax.BeginForm` to do its stuff before the last line of the `success` clause has been executed, hence 0.

Can anyone advise on a way to make the second form delay submission until I know the last line of the `success` clause has been completed?

Comment: Remove `async: false`. It's incredibly bad practices as it locks up the browser's UI thread. If you check the console the browser will even be giving you warnings not to use synchronous requests

Comment: Get rid of `Ajax.BeginForm()` and just use `$.ajax()` (your already using it so why would you want Ajax.BeginForm() anyway). Handle the `.submit()` event, make you ajax call to get the coordinates, and in its success callback, make you ajax call to `EditLocation()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `false` from your function:

```
var allowSubmit = false;
function OnBegin() {
    if (allowSubmit == true) { return true; }
    $.ajax({
        // ... code
        success: function (data) {
            // ... code
            // here you need to submit the form using 
            $( "#EditLocationForm" ).submit()
            allowSubmit = true;
        },
        error: function (response) {
          // .. code
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

In `success`, submit the form as shown in code above.

Also, do not do this using `async: false`: you do not want to freeze the UI while that operation is going on. What you may want to do is to disable the controls so the user cannot change them and then re-enable them in `success` and `error`.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but it goes into a continuous loop of calling the initial AJAX call over and over. Any advice here? I had this setup earlier but abandoned it, after this happened.